# Refactored a script in order to understand it but I'm now experiencing a bug I can't seem to solve

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been playing around with trying to do an active ragdoll when I came across a script that Youtube user MetalCore999 had created (First script below). I tried refactoring this code so that I would understand what he had done to make this work, and eventually improving upon it myself however I've hit a brick wall and cannot seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The problem that I am experiencing is that in the original script by MetalCore999, the character stands up on its own when there is no input, however in my version of the script the character decides to just squat down.

I've tried reading through each element and checking if there is some piece of code that is not being called properly but I cannot for the life of me figure out where this bug is at.

Here is the original script by MetalCore999:

```
   using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] PlayerParts;
    public ConfigurableJoint[] JointParts;
    Vector3 COM;
    public float TouchForce, TimeStep, LegsHeight, FallFactor;
    float Step_R_Time, Step_L_Time;
    public bool StepR, StepL,  WalkF, WalkB, Falling, Fall, StandUp;
    bool flag, Flag_Leg_R, Flag_Leg_L;
    Quaternion StartLegR1, StartLegR2, StartLegL1, StartLegL2;
    JointDrive Spring0, Spring150, Spring300, Spring320;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(PlayerParts[2].GetComponent<Collider>(), PlayerParts[4].GetComponent<Collider>(), true);
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(PlayerParts[3].GetComponent<Collider>(), PlayerParts[7].GetComponent<Collider>(), true);
        StartLegR1 = PlayerParts[4].GetComponent<ConfigurableJoint>().targetRotation;
        StartLegR2 = PlayerParts[5].GetComponent<ConfigurableJoint>().targetRotation;
        StartLegL1 = PlayerParts[7].GetComponent<ConfigurableJoint>().targetRotation;
        StartLegL2 = PlayerParts[8].GetComponent<ConfigurableJoint>().targetRotation;

        Spring0 = new JointDrive();
        Spring0.positionSpring = 0;
        Spring0.positionDamper = 0;
        Spring0.maximumForce = Mathf.Infinity;

        Spring150 = new JointDrive();
        Spring150.positionSpring = 150;
        Spring150.positionDamper = 0;
        Spring150.maximumForce = Mathf.Infinity;

        Spring300 = new JointDrive();
        Spring300.positionSpring = 300;
        Spring300.positionDamper = 100;
        Spring300.maximumForce = Mathf.Infinity;

        Spring320 = new JointDrive();
        Spring320.positionSpring = 320;
        Spring320.positionDamper = 0;
        Spring320.maximumForce = Mathf.Infinity;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        PlayerParts[12].transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(PlayerParts[12].transform.position, PlayerParts[2].transform.position, 2 * Time.unscaledDeltaTime);

        #region Input
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            PlayerParts[0].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.back * TouchForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            PlayerParts[0].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.forward * TouchForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            if (Time.timeScale == 1)
                Time.timeScale = 0.4f;
            else
                Time.timeScale = 1;
        }

        #endregion

        Calculate_COM();

        PlayerParts[10].transform.position = COM;

        Balance();

        PlayerParts[11].transform.LookAt(PlayerParts[10].transform.position);

        if (!WalkF && !WalkB)
        {
            StepR = false;
            StepL = false;
            Step_R_Time = 0;
            Step_L_Time = 0;
            Flag_Leg_R = false;
            Flag_Leg_L = false;
            JointParts[0].targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(JointParts[0].targetRotation, new Quaternion(-0.1f, JointParts[0].targetRotation.y, JointParts[0].targetRotation.z, JointParts[0].targetRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {      
        LegsMoving();
    }

    void Balance()
    {
        if (PlayerParts[10].transform.position.z < PlayerParts[6].transform.position.z && PlayerParts[10].transform.position.z < PlayerParts[9].transform.position.z)
        {
            WalkB = true;
            JointParts[0].targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(JointParts[0].targetRotation, new Quaternion(-0.1f, JointParts[0].targetRotation.y, JointParts[0].targetRotation.z, JointParts[0].targetRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            WalkB = false;
        }

        if (PlayerParts[10].transform.position.z > PlayerParts[6].transform.position.z && PlayerParts[10].transform.position.z > PlayerParts[9].transform.position.z)
        {
            WalkF = true;
            JointParts[0].targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(JointParts[0].targetRotation, new Quaternion(0, JointParts[0].targetRotation.y, JointParts[0].targetRotation.z, JointParts[0].targetRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            WalkF = false;
        }

        if (PlayerParts[10].transform.position.z > PlayerParts[6].transform.position.z + FallFactor &&
           PlayerParts[10].transform.position.z > PlayerParts[9].transform.position.z + FallFactor ||
           PlayerParts[10].transform.position.z < PlayerParts[6].transform.position.z - (FallFactor + 0.2f) &&
           PlayerParts[10].transform.position.z < PlayerParts[9].transform.position.z - (FallFactor + 0.2f))
        {
            Falling = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Falling = false;
        }

        if (Falling)
        {
            JointParts[1].angularXDrive = Spring0;
            JointParts[1].angularYZDrive = Spring0;
            LegsHeight = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            JointParts[1].angularXDrive = Spring300;
            JointParts[1].angularYZDrive = Spring300;
            LegsHeight = 1;
            JointParts[2].targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(JointParts[2].targetRotation, new Quaternion(0, JointParts[2].targetRotation.y, JointParts[2].targetRotation.z, JointParts[2].targetRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            JointParts[3].targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(JointParts[3].targetRotation, new Quaternion(0, JointParts[3].targetRotation.y, JointParts[3].targetRotation.z, JointParts[3].targetRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            JointParts[2].angularXDrive = Spring0;
            JointParts[2].angularYZDrive = Spring150;
            JointParts[3].angularXDrive = Spring0;
            JointParts[3].angularYZDrive = Spring150;
        }

        if (PlayerParts[0].transform.position.y - 0.1f <= PlayerParts[1].transform.position.y)
        {
            Fall = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Fall = false;
        }

        if (Fall)
        {
            JointParts[1].angularXDrive = Spring0;
            JointParts[1].angularYZDrive = Spring0;
            StandUping();           
        }
    }

    void LegsMoving()
    {
        if (WalkF)
        {
            if (PlayerParts[6].transform.position.z < PlayerParts[9].transform.position.z && !StepL && !Flag_Leg_R)
            {
                StepR = true;
                Flag_Leg_R = true;
                Flag_Leg_L = true;
            }
            if (PlayerParts[6].transform.position.z > PlayerParts[9].transform.position.z && !StepR && !Flag_Leg_L)
            {
                StepL = true;
                Flag_Leg_L = true;
                Flag_Leg_R = true;
            }
        }

        if (WalkB)
        {
            if (PlayerParts[6].transform.position.z > PlayerParts[9].transform.position.z && !StepL && !Flag_Leg_R)
            {
                StepR = true;
                Flag_Leg_R = true;
                Flag_Leg_L = true;
            }
            if (PlayerParts[6].transform.position.z < PlayerParts[9].transform.position.z && !StepR && !Flag_Leg_L)
            {
                StepL = true;
                Flag_Leg_L = true;
                Flag_Leg_R = true;
            }
        }

        if (StepR)
        {
            Step_R_Time += Time.fixedDeltaTime;

            if (WalkF)
            {                
                JointParts[4].targetRotation = new Quaternion(JointParts[4].targetRotation.x + 0.07f * LegsHeight, JointParts[4].targetRotation.y, JointParts[4].targetRotation.z, JointParts[4].targetRotation.w);
                JointParts[5].targetRotation = new Quaternion(JointParts[5].targetRotation.x - 0.04f * LegsHeight * 2, JointParts[5].targetRotation.y, JointParts[5].targetRotation.z, JointParts[5].targetRotation.w);

                JointParts[7].targetRotation = new Quaternion(JointParts[7].targetRotation.x - 0.02f * LegsHeight / 2, JointParts[7].targetRotation.y, JointParts[7].targetRotation.z, JointParts[7].targetRotation.w);
            }

            if (WalkB)
            {
                JointParts[4].targetRotation = new Quaternion(JointParts[4].targetRotation.x - 0.00f * LegsHeight, JointParts[4].targetRotation.y, JointParts[4].targetRotation.z, JointParts[4].targetRotation.w);
                JointParts[5].targetRotation = new Quaternion(JointParts[5].targetRotation.x - 0.06f * LegsHeight * 2, JointParts[5].targetRotation.y, JointParts[5].targetRotation.z, JointParts[5].targetRotation.w);

                JointParts[7].targetRotation = new Quaternion(JointParts[7].targetRotation.x + 0.02f * LegsHeight / 2, JointParts[7].targetRotation.y, JointParts[7].targetRotation.z, JointParts[7].targetRotation.w);
            }

            if (Step_R_Time > TimeStep)
            {
                Step_R_Time = 0;
                StepR = false;

                if (WalkB || WalkF)
                {
                    StepL = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            JointParts[4].targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(JointParts[4].targetRotation, StartLegR1, (8f) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            JointParts[5].targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(JointParts[5].targetRotation, StartLegR2, (17f) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }

        if (StepL)
        {
            Step_L_Time += Time.fixedDeltaTime;

            if (WalkF)
            {
                JointParts[7].targetRotation = new Quaternion(JointParts[7].targetRotation.x + 0.07f * LegsHeight, JointParts[7].targetRotation.y, JointParts[7].targetRotation.z, JointParts[7].targetRotation.w);
                JointParts[8].targetRotation = new Quaternion(JointParts[8].targetRotation.x - 0.04f * LegsHeight * 2, JointParts[8].targetRotation.y, JointParts[8].targetRotation.z, JointParts[8].targetRotation.w);

                JointParts[4].targetRotation = new Quaternion(JointParts[4].targetRotation.x - 0.02f * LegsHeight / 2, JointParts[4].targetRotation.y, JointParts[4].targetRotation.z, JointParts[4].targetRotation.w);
            }

            if (WalkB)
            {
                JointParts[7].targetRotation = new Quaternion(JointParts[7].targetRotation.x - 0.00f * LegsHeight, JointParts[7].targetRotation.y, JointParts[7].targetRotation.z, JointParts[7].targetRotation.w);
                JointParts[8].targetRotation = new Quaternion(JointParts[8].targetRotation.x - 0.06f * LegsHeight * 2, JointParts[8].targetRotation.y, JointParts[8].targetRotation.z, JointParts[8].targetRotation.w);

                JointParts[4].targetRotation = new Quaternion(JointParts[4].targetRotation.x + 0.02f * LegsHeight / 2, JointParts[4].targetRotation.y, JointParts[4].targetRotation.z, JointParts[4].targetRotation.w);
            }

            if (Step_L_Time > TimeStep)
            {
                Step_L_Time = 0;
                StepL = false;

                if (WalkB || WalkF)
                {
                    StepR = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            JointParts[7].targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(JointParts[7].targetRotation, StartLegL1, (8) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            JointParts[8].targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(JointParts[8].targetRotation, StartLegL2, (17) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
    }

    void StandUping()
    {
        if (WalkF)
        {
            JointParts[2].angularXDrive = Spring320;
            JointParts[2].angularYZDrive = Spring320;
            JointParts[3].angularXDrive = Spring320;
            JointParts[3].angularYZDrive = Spring320;
            JointParts[0].targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(JointParts[0].targetRotation, new Quaternion(-0.1f, JointParts[0].targetRotation.y, 
                JointParts[0].targetRotation.z, JointParts[0].targetRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

            if (JointParts[2].targetRotation.x < 1.7f)
            {
                JointParts[2].targetRotation = new Quaternion(JointParts[2].targetRotation.x + 0.07f, JointParts[2].targetRotation.y, 
                    JointParts[2].targetRotation.z, JointParts[2].targetRotation.w);
            }

            if (JointParts[3].targetRotation.x < 1.7f)
            {
                JointParts[3].targetRotation = new Quaternion(JointParts[3].targetRotation.x + 0.07f, JointParts[3].targetRotation.y, 
                    JointParts[3].targetRotation.z, JointParts[3].targetRotation.w);
            }
        }

        if (WalkB)
        {
            JointParts[2].angularXDrive = Spring320;
            JointParts[2].angularYZDrive = Spring320;
            JointParts[3].angularXDrive = Spring320;
            JointParts[3].angularYZDrive = Spring320;

            if (JointParts[2].targetRotation.x > -1.7f)
            {
                JointParts[2].targetRotation = new Quaternion(JointParts[2].targetRotation.x - 0.09f, JointParts[2].targetRotation.y, 
                    JointParts[2].targetRotation.z, JointParts[2].targetRotation.w);
            }

            if (JointParts[3].targetRotation.x > -1.7f)
            {
                JointParts[3].targetRotation = new Quaternion(JointParts[3].targetRotation.x - 0.09f, JointParts[3].targetRotation.y, 
                    JointParts[3].targetRotation.z, JointParts[3].targetRotation.w);
            }
        }
    }

    void Calculate_COM()
    {
        COM = (JointParts[0].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass * JointParts[0].transform.position + 
            JointParts[1].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass * JointParts[1].transform.position +
            JointParts[2].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass * JointParts[2].transform.position +
            JointParts[3].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass * JointParts[3].transform.position +
            JointParts[4].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass * JointParts[4].transform.position +
            JointParts[5].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass * JointParts[5].transform.position +
            JointParts[6].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass * JointParts[6].transform.position +
            JointParts[7].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass * JointParts[7].transform.position +
            JointParts[8].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass * JointParts[8].transform.position +
            JointParts[9].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass * JointParts[9].transform.position) /
            (JointParts[0].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass + JointParts[1].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass +
            JointParts[2].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass + JointParts[3].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass +
            JointParts[4].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass + JointParts[5].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass +
            JointParts[6].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass + JointParts[7].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass +
            JointParts[8].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass + JointParts[9].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass);
    }
}
```

And here is my version of it (and below that you'll find my data class for the rig):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ActiveRagdoll : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Inspector
    [Header("Ragdoll Rig")] 
    [SerializeField] private RagdollRig rig;

    [Header("Movement")] 
    [SerializeField] private float touchForce;
    [SerializeField] private float timeStep;
    [SerializeField] private float legHeight;
    [SerializeField] private float fallFactor;

    #endregion

    #region Variables
    private float _rightStepTime, _leftStepTime;
    private bool _stepRight, _stepLeft, _walkForward, _walkBackwards, _falling;
    private bool _flag, _flagRightLeg, _flagLeftLeg;

    private Quaternion _startLegR1, _startLegR2, _startLegL1, _startLegL2;
    private JointDrive _spring0, _spring150, _spring300, _spring320;
    private Rigidbody _body;
    #endregion

    private void Awake()
    {
        _body = rig.torso.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        Physics.IgnoreCollision(rig.rightArm.GetComponent<Collider>(),
            rig.upperRightLeg.GetComponent<Collider>());
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(rig.leftArm.GetComponent<Collider>(),
            rig.upperLeftLeg.GetComponent<Collider>());

        SetupSprings();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var input = Vector2.zero;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            input = new Vector2(0, 1);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            input = new Vector2(0, -1);
        }

        Movement(input);
    }

    public void Movement(Vector2 input)
    {
        if (input.y < -.3f)
            _body.AddForce(Vector3.back * touchForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        else if (input.y > .3f)
            _body.AddForce(Vector3.forward * touchForce, ForceMode.Impulse);

        if (input.x < -.3f)
        {
            //TODO: ROTATE
        }
        else if (input.x > .3f)
        {
            //TODO: ROTATE
        }

        rig.centerOfMass.position = rig.CalculateCenterOfMass();
        Balance();

        if (!_walkForward && !_walkBackwards)
            ResetMovement();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MoveLegs();
    }

    private void Balance()
    {
        var comPosition = rig.centerOfMass.position;
        var rightFootPosition = rig.rightFoot.transform.position;
        var leftFootPosition = rig.leftFoot.transform.position;

        if (comPosition.z < rightFootPosition.z && comPosition.z < leftFootPosition.z)
        {
            var targetRotation = rig.torso.targetRotation;

            _walkBackwards = true;
            rig.torso.targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(targetRotation, new Quaternion(-0.1f, targetRotation.y,
                    targetRotation.z, targetRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
        else
            _walkBackwards = false;

        if (comPosition.z > rightFootPosition.z && comPosition.z > leftFootPosition.z)
        {
            var targetRotation = rig.torso.targetRotation;

            _walkForward = true;
            rig.torso.targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(targetRotation,
                new Quaternion(0, targetRotation.y, targetRotation.z, targetRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
        else
            _walkForward = false;

        _falling = comPosition.z > rightFootPosition.z + fallFactor && comPosition.z > leftFootPosition.z + fallFactor ||
                   comPosition.z < rightFootPosition.z - (fallFactor + 0.2f) && comPosition.z < leftFootPosition.z - (fallFactor + 0.2f);

        if (_falling)
        {
            rig.pelvis.angularXDrive = _spring0;
            rig.pelvis.angularYZDrive = _spring0;
            legHeight = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            rig.pelvis.angularXDrive = _spring300;
            rig.pelvis.angularYZDrive = _spring300;
            legHeight = 1;

            var rightArmRotation = rig.rightArm.targetRotation;
            var leftArmRotation = rig.leftArm.targetRotation;

            rig.rightArm.targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(rightArmRotation,
                new Quaternion(0, rightArmRotation.y, rightArmRotation.z, rightArmRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            rig.leftArm.targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(leftArmRotation,
                new Quaternion(0, leftArmRotation.y, leftArmRotation.z, leftArmRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

            rig.rightArm.angularXDrive = _spring0;
            rig.rightArm.angularYZDrive = _spring150;
            rig.leftArm.angularXDrive = _spring0;
            rig.leftArm.angularYZDrive = _spring150;
        }

        if (!(rig.torso.transform.position.y - 0.1f <= rig.pelvis.transform.position.y)) return;
        rig.pelvis.angularXDrive = _spring0;
        rig.pelvis.angularYZDrive = _spring0;
        StandUp();
    }

    private void MoveLegs()
    {
        if (_walkForward)
        {
            if (rig.rightFoot.transform.position.z < rig.leftFoot.transform.position.z && !_stepLeft && !_flagRightLeg)
                _stepRight = _flagRightLeg = _flagLeftLeg = true;

            if (rig.rightFoot.transform.position.z > rig.leftFoot.transform.position.z && !_stepRight && !_flagLeftLeg)
                _stepLeft = _flagLeftLeg = _flagRightLeg = true;
        }
        else if (_walkBackwards)
        {
            if (rig.rightFoot.transform.position.z > rig.leftFoot.transform.position.z && !_stepLeft && !_flagRightLeg)
                _stepRight = _flagRightLeg = _flagLeftLeg = true;

            if (rig.rightFoot.transform.position.z < rig.leftFoot.transform.position.z && !_stepRight && !_flagLeftLeg)
                _stepLeft = _flagLeftLeg = _flagRightLeg = true;
        }

        TakeSteps();
    }

    private void TakeSteps()
    {
        if (_stepRight)
        {
            _rightStepTime += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            CalculateStep(ref rig.upperRightLeg, ref rig.lowerRightLeg, ref rig.upperLeftLeg);

            if (_rightStepTime > timeStep)
            {
                _rightStepTime = 0;
                _stepRight = false;

                if (_walkBackwards || _walkForward)
                    _stepLeft = true;
            }
        }
        else
            LerpLegs(ref rig.upperRightLeg, ref rig.lowerRightLeg, _startLegR1, _startLegR2);

        if (_stepLeft)
        {
            _leftStepTime += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            CalculateStep(ref rig.upperLeftLeg, ref rig.lowerLeftLeg, ref rig.upperRightLeg);

            if (_leftStepTime > timeStep)
            {
                _leftStepTime = 0;
                _stepLeft = false;

                if (_walkBackwards || _walkForward)
                    _stepRight = true;
            }
        }
        else
            LerpLegs(ref rig.upperLeftLeg, ref rig.lowerLeftLeg, _startLegL1, _startLegL2);
    }

    private void StandUp()
    {
        rig.rightArm.angularXDrive = _spring320;
        rig.rightArm.angularYZDrive = _spring320;
        rig.leftArm.angularXDrive = _spring320;
        rig.leftArm.angularYZDrive = _spring320;

        if (_walkForward)
        {
            var targetRotation = rig.torso.targetRotation;

            rig.torso.targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(targetRotation,
                new Quaternion(-.1f, targetRotation.y, targetRotation.z,
                    targetRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

            RotateArmInDirection(ref rig.rightArm, 1.7f);
            RotateArmInDirection(ref rig.leftArm, 1.7f);
        }

        if (!_walkBackwards) return;
        RotateArmInDirection(ref rig.rightArm, -1.7f);
        RotateArmInDirection(ref rig.leftArm, -1.7f);
    }

    private void ResetMovement()
    {
        _stepRight = _stepLeft = false;
        _rightStepTime = _leftStepTime = 0;
        _flagRightLeg = _flagLeftLeg = false;

        var targetRotation = rig.torso.targetRotation;
        rig.torso.targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(targetRotation,
            new Quaternion(-.1f, targetRotation.y, targetRotation.z, targetRotation.w),
            6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    private void SetupSprings()
    {
        _spring0 = new JointDrive
        {
            positionSpring = 0, positionDamper = 0,
            maximumForce = Mathf.Infinity
        };

        _spring150 = new JointDrive
        {
            positionSpring = 150, positionDamper = 0,
            maximumForce = Mathf.Infinity
        };

        _spring300 = new JointDrive
        {
            positionSpring = 300, positionDamper = 100,
            maximumForce = Mathf.Infinity
        };

        _spring320 = new JointDrive
        {
            positionSpring = 320, positionDamper = 0,
            maximumForce = Mathf.Infinity
        };
    }

    private void RotateArmInDirection(ref ConfigurableJoint arm, float limit)
    {
        if (arm.targetRotation.x < limit)
        {
            var targetRotation = arm.targetRotation;
            arm.targetRotation = new Quaternion(targetRotation.x + .07f, targetRotation.y,
                targetRotation.z, targetRotation.w);
        }
        else if (arm.targetRotation.x < limit)
        {
            var targetRotation = arm.targetRotation;
            arm.targetRotation = new Quaternion(targetRotation.x - .09f, targetRotation.y, targetRotation.z,
                targetRotation.w);
        }
    }

    private void LerpLegs(ref ConfigurableJoint upperLeg, ref ConfigurableJoint lowerLeg, Quaternion upperStart, Quaternion lowerStart)
    {
        upperLeg.targetRotation =
            Quaternion.Lerp(upperLeg.targetRotation, upperStart, 8f * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        lowerLeg.targetRotation =
            Quaternion.Lerp(lowerLeg.targetRotation, lowerStart, 17f * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    private void CalculateStep(ref ConfigurableJoint upperDominant, ref ConfigurableJoint lowerDominant,
        ref ConfigurableJoint upperSupport)
    {
        var upperDominantRotation = upperDominant.targetRotation;
        var lowerDominantRotation = lowerDominant.targetRotation;
        var upperSupportRotation = upperSupport.targetRotation;

        if (_walkForward)
        {
            upperDominant.targetRotation = new Quaternion(upperDominantRotation.x + 0.07f * legHeight, upperDominantRotation.y, 
                upperDominantRotation.z, upperDominantRotation.w);

            lowerDominant.targetRotation = new Quaternion(lowerDominantRotation.x - 0.04f * legHeight * 2,
                lowerDominantRotation.y, lowerDominantRotation.z, lowerDominantRotation.w);

            upperSupport.targetRotation = new Quaternion(upperSupportRotation.x - 0.02f * legHeight / 2,
                upperSupportRotation.y, upperSupportRotation.z, upperSupportRotation.w);
        }

        if (!_walkBackwards) return;
        upperDominant.targetRotation = new Quaternion(upperDominantRotation.x - 0.00f * legHeight, upperDominantRotation.y, 
            upperDominantRotation.z, upperDominantRotation.w);

        lowerDominant.targetRotation = new Quaternion(lowerDominantRotation.x - 0.06f * legHeight * 2,
            lowerDominantRotation.y, lowerDominantRotation.z, lowerDominantRotation.w);

        upperSupport.targetRotation = new Quaternion(upperSupportRotation.x + 0.02f * legHeight / 2,
            upperSupportRotation.y, upperSupportRotation.z, upperSupportRotation.w);
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class RagdollRig
{
    public ConfigurableJoint torso,
        pelvis,
        rightArm,
        leftArm,
        upperRightLeg,
        lowerRightLeg,
        rightFoot,
        upperLeftLeg,
        lowerLeftLeg,
        leftFoot;

    public Transform centerOfMass;

    private List<Rigidbody> GetRigidbodies()
    {
        return new List<Rigidbody>
        {
            torso.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            pelvis.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            rightArm.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            leftArm.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            upperRightLeg.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            lowerRightLeg.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            rightFoot.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            upperLeftLeg.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            lowerLeftLeg.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            leftFoot.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()
        };
    }

    public Vector3 CalculateCenterOfMass()
    {
        var parts = GetRigidbodies();
        var mass = Vector3.zero;
        float division = 0;

        foreach (var t in parts)
        {
            var objMass = t.mass;
            mass += objMass * t.transform.position;
            division += objMass;
        }

        return mass / division;
    }
}
```

Just to make it a bit easier for you to check out [here is a dropbox link to the Unity project itself](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysbyt8c9fsr31en/active_ragdoll.zip?dl=0).

Any tips or ideas on how to fix this is really appreciated!

Comment: Did you try [debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) your code?

Comment: @derHugo I did and couldn't really seem to detect where I went wrong, although at that stage I had been looking at it for a long time so I might have been doing something wrong or just blind.

Comment: Tried debugging it, still can't seem to figure out where the bug is occurring @derHugo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I ended up just deleting my refactored code above (except the ragdoll rig class) and start over.

I'm not a 100% certain as to why it didn't work before but I think I might have swapped some variables a couple of places.

Some of the functions that I created in the previous script might also have been the culprit so I decided to not go with the ref functions that I created.

Anyways, this is what I ended up with, hope it's useful to anyone who might want to toy around with active ragdolls

``

```
using UnityEngine;
using Quaternion = UnityEngine.Quaternion;
using Vector2 = UnityEngine.Vector2;
using Vector3 = UnityEngine.Vector3;

public class ActiveRagdoll : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Inspector

    [Header("Ragdoll Rig")] [SerializeField]
    private RagdollRig rig;

    [Header("Movement")] [SerializeField] private float touchForce;
    [SerializeField] private float timeStep;
    [SerializeField] private float legHeight;
    [SerializeField] private float fallFactor;

    #endregion

    #region Variables
    private float _rightStepTime, _leftStepTime;
    private bool _stepRight, _stepLeft, _walkForward, _walkBackwards, _falling;
    private bool _flag, _flagRightLeg, _flagLeftLeg;

    private Quaternion _startLegR1, _startLegR2, _startLegL1, _startLegL2;
    private JointDrive _spring0, _spring150, _spring300, _spring320;
    private Rigidbody _body;
    #endregion

    private void Awake()
    {
        rig.InitializeRig();
        _body = rig.torso.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        Physics.IgnoreCollision(rig.rightArm.GetComponent<Collider>(), rig.upperRightLeg.GetComponent<Collider>(),
            true);
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(rig.leftArm.GetComponent<Collider>(), rig.upperLeftLeg.GetComponent<Collider>(), true);

        SetupJoints();
    }

    //FOR TESTING, REMOVE LATER
    private void Update()
    {
        MovementInput(new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical")));
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        LegsMoving();
    }

    public void MovementInput(Vector2 input)
    {
        var direction = new Vector3(input.x, 0, input.y);

        if (input.y < 0 || input.y > 0)
            _body.AddForce(Time.fixedDeltaTime * touchForce * direction, ForceMode.Impulse);

        rig.centerOfMass.position = rig.CalculateCenterOfMass();

        Balance();

        if (!_walkForward && !_walkBackwards)
            ResetMovement();
    }

    private void ResetMovement()
    {
        var targetRotation = rig.torso.targetRotation;

        _stepRight = false;
        _stepLeft = false;
        _rightStepTime = 0;
        _leftStepTime = 0;
        _flagRightLeg = false;
        _flagLeftLeg = false;

        rig.torso.targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(targetRotation,
            new Quaternion(-0.1f, targetRotation.y, targetRotation.z, targetRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    private void Balance()
    {
        var comPosition = rig.centerOfMass.transform.position;
        var rightFootPosition = rig.rightFoot.transform.position;
        var leftFootPosition = rig.leftFoot.transform.position;
        var targetRotation = rig.torso.targetRotation;

        _walkBackwards = comPosition.z < rightFootPosition.z && comPosition.z < leftFootPosition.z;

        if (_walkBackwards)
            rig.torso.targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(targetRotation,
                new Quaternion(-0.1f, targetRotation.y, targetRotation.z, targetRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        _walkForward = comPosition.z > rightFootPosition.z && comPosition.z > leftFootPosition.z;

        if (_walkForward)
            rig.torso.targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(targetRotation,
                new Quaternion(0, targetRotation.y, targetRotation.z, targetRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        CheckForFall(comPosition, rightFootPosition, leftFootPosition);

        if (!(rig.torso.transform.position.y - 0.1f <= rig.pelvis.transform.position.y)) return;
        rig.pelvis.angularXDrive = _spring0;
        rig.pelvis.angularYZDrive = _spring0;
        StandUp();
    }

    private void LegsMoving()
    {
        var upperRightLegRotation = rig.upperRightLeg.targetRotation;
        var lowerRightLegRotation = rig.lowerRightLeg.targetRotation;
        var upperLeftLegRotation = rig.upperLeftLeg.targetRotation;
        var lowerLeftLegRotation = rig.lowerLeftLeg.targetRotation;

        CheckFooting(rig.rightFoot.transform.position, rig.leftFoot.transform.position);

        if (_stepRight)
        {
            _rightStepTime += Time.fixedDeltaTime;

            if (_walkForward)
            {
                rig.upperRightLeg.targetRotation = new Quaternion(upperRightLegRotation.x + 0.07f * legHeight, upperRightLegRotation.y,
                    upperRightLegRotation.z, upperRightLegRotation.w);

                rig.lowerRightLeg.targetRotation = new Quaternion(lowerRightLegRotation.x - 0.04f * legHeight * 2, lowerRightLegRotation.y,
                    lowerRightLegRotation.z, lowerRightLegRotation.w);

                rig.upperLeftLeg.targetRotation = new Quaternion(upperLeftLegRotation.x - 0.02f * legHeight / 2, upperLeftLegRotation.y, 
                    upperLeftLegRotation.z, upperLeftLegRotation.w);
            }

            if (_walkBackwards)
            {
                rig.upperRightLeg.targetRotation = new Quaternion(upperRightLegRotation.x - 0.00f * legHeight, upperRightLegRotation.y, 
                    upperRightLegRotation.z, upperRightLegRotation.w);

                rig.lowerRightLeg.targetRotation = new Quaternion(lowerRightLegRotation.x - 0.06f * legHeight * 2, lowerRightLegRotation.y,
                    lowerRightLegRotation.z, lowerRightLegRotation.w);

                rig.upperLeftLeg.targetRotation = new Quaternion(upperLeftLegRotation.x + 0.02f * legHeight / 2, upperLeftLegRotation.y, 
                    upperLeftLegRotation.z, upperLeftLegRotation.w);
            }

            if (_rightStepTime > timeStep)
            {
                _rightStepTime = 0;
                _stepRight = false;
                _stepLeft = _walkBackwards || _walkForward;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rig.upperRightLeg.targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(upperRightLegRotation, _startLegR1,
                8f * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            rig.lowerRightLeg.targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(lowerRightLegRotation, _startLegR2,
                17f * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }

        if (_stepLeft)
        {
            _leftStepTime += Time.fixedDeltaTime;

            if (_walkForward)
            {
                rig.upperLeftLeg.targetRotation = new Quaternion(upperLeftLegRotation.x + 0.07f * legHeight, upperLeftLegRotation.y, 
                    upperLeftLegRotation.z, upperLeftLegRotation.w);

                rig.lowerLeftLeg.targetRotation = new Quaternion(lowerLeftLegRotation.x - 0.04f * legHeight * 2, lowerLeftLegRotation.y, 
                    lowerLeftLegRotation.z, lowerLeftLegRotation.w);

                rig.upperRightLeg.targetRotation = new Quaternion(upperRightLegRotation.x - 0.02f * legHeight / 2, upperRightLegRotation.y,
                    upperRightLegRotation.z, upperRightLegRotation.w);
            }

            if (_walkBackwards)
            {
                rig.upperLeftLeg.targetRotation = new Quaternion(upperLeftLegRotation.x - 0.00f * legHeight,
                    upperLeftLegRotation.y, upperLeftLegRotation.z, upperLeftLegRotation.w);

                rig.lowerLeftLeg.targetRotation = new Quaternion(lowerLeftLegRotation.x - 0.06f * legHeight * 2,
                        lowerLeftLegRotation.y, lowerLeftLegRotation.z, lowerLeftLegRotation.w);

                rig.upperRightLeg.targetRotation = new Quaternion(upperRightLegRotation.x + 0.02f * legHeight / 2, 
                    upperRightLegRotation.y, upperRightLegRotation.z, upperRightLegRotation.w);
            }

            if (_leftStepTime > timeStep)
            {
                _leftStepTime = 0;
                _stepLeft = false;
                _stepRight = _walkBackwards || _walkForward;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rig.upperLeftLeg.targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(upperLeftLegRotation, _startLegL1, (8) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            rig.lowerLeftLeg.targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(lowerLeftLegRotation, _startLegL2, (17) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
    }

    private void CheckFooting(Vector3 rightFoot, Vector3 leftFoot)
    {
        if (_walkForward)
        {
            if (rightFoot.z < leftFoot.z && !_stepLeft && !_flagRightLeg)
                _stepRight = _flagRightLeg = _flagLeftLeg = true;

            if (rightFoot.z > leftFoot.z && !_stepRight && !_flagLeftLeg)
                _stepLeft = _flagLeftLeg = _flagRightLeg = true;
        }

        if (!_walkBackwards) return;
        if (rightFoot.z > leftFoot.z && !_stepLeft && !_flagRightLeg)
            _stepRight = _flagRightLeg = _flagLeftLeg = true;

        if (rightFoot.z < leftFoot.z && !_stepRight && !_flagLeftLeg)
            _stepLeft = _flagLeftLeg = _flagRightLeg = true;
    }

    private void StandUp()
    {
        var leftArmRotation = rig.leftArm.targetRotation;
        var rightArmRotation = rig.rightArm.targetRotation;
        var torsoRotation = rig.torso.targetRotation;

        rig.rightArm.angularXDrive = _spring320;
        rig.rightArm.angularYZDrive = _spring320;
        rig.leftArm.angularXDrive = _spring320;
        rig.leftArm.angularYZDrive = _spring320;

        if (_walkForward)
        {
            rig.torso.targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(torsoRotation, new Quaternion(-0.1f,
                    torsoRotation.y,torsoRotation.z, torsoRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

            if (rightArmRotation.x < 1.7f)
                rig.rightArm.targetRotation = new Quaternion(rightArmRotation.x + 0.07f,
                    rightArmRotation.y,rightArmRotation.z, rightArmRotation.w);

            if (leftArmRotation.x < 1.7f)
                rig.leftArm.targetRotation = new Quaternion(leftArmRotation.x + 0.07f,
                    leftArmRotation.y,leftArmRotation.z, leftArmRotation.w);
        }

        if (_walkBackwards)
        {
            if (rightArmRotation.x > -1.7f)
                rig.rightArm.targetRotation = new Quaternion(rightArmRotation.x - 0.09f,
                    rightArmRotation.y,rightArmRotation.z, rightArmRotation.w);

            if (leftArmRotation.x > -1.7f)
                rig.leftArm.targetRotation = new Quaternion(leftArmRotation.x - 0.09f,
                    leftArmRotation.y,leftArmRotation.z, leftArmRotation.w);
        }
    }

    private void CheckForFall(Vector3 comPosition, Vector3 rightFootPosition, Vector3 leftFootPosition)
    {
        _falling = comPosition.z > rightFootPosition.z + fallFactor && comPosition.z > leftFootPosition.z + fallFactor ||
                   comPosition.z < rightFootPosition.z - (fallFactor + 0.2f) && comPosition.z < leftFootPosition.z - (fallFactor + 0.2f);

        if (_falling)
        {
            rig.pelvis.angularXDrive = _spring0;
            rig.pelvis.angularYZDrive = _spring0;
            legHeight = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            var rightArmRotation = rig.rightArm.targetRotation;
            var leftArmRotation = rig.leftArm.targetRotation;

            rig.pelvis.angularXDrive = _spring300;
            rig.pelvis.angularYZDrive = _spring300;
            legHeight = 1;

            rig.rightArm.targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(rightArmRotation,
                new Quaternion(0, rightArmRotation.y, rightArmRotation.z, rightArmRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

            rig.leftArm.targetRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(leftArmRotation,
                new Quaternion(0, leftArmRotation.y, leftArmRotation.z, leftArmRotation.w), 6 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

            rig.rightArm.angularXDrive = _spring0;
            rig.rightArm.angularYZDrive = _spring150;
            rig.leftArm.angularXDrive = _spring0;
            rig.leftArm.angularYZDrive = _spring150;
        }
    }

    private void SetupJoints()
    {
        _startLegR1 = rig.upperRightLeg.targetRotation;
        _startLegR2 = rig.lowerRightLeg.targetRotation;
        _startLegL1 = rig.upperLeftLeg.targetRotation;
        _startLegL2 = rig.lowerLeftLeg.targetRotation;

        _spring0 = new JointDrive {positionSpring = 0, positionDamper = 0, maximumForce = Mathf.Infinity};
        _spring150 = new JointDrive {positionSpring = 150, positionDamper = 0, maximumForce = Mathf.Infinity};
        _spring300 = new JointDrive {positionSpring = 300, positionDamper = 100, maximumForce = Mathf.Infinity};
        _spring320 = new JointDrive {positionSpring = 320, positionDamper = 0, maximumForce = Mathf.Infinity};
    }
}
```

``

and then the rig class

``

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class RagdollRig
{
    public ConfigurableJoint torso,
        pelvis,
        rightArm,
        leftArm,
        upperRightLeg,
        lowerRightLeg,
        rightFoot,
        upperLeftLeg,
        lowerLeftLeg,
        leftFoot;

    public Transform centerOfMass;

    private List<Rigidbody> _rigidbodies;

    public void InitializeRig()
    {
        _rigidbodies = GetRigidbodies();
    }

    private List<Rigidbody> GetRigidbodies()
    {
        return new List<Rigidbody>
        {
            torso.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            pelvis.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            rightArm.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            leftArm.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            upperRightLeg.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            lowerRightLeg.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            rightFoot.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            upperLeftLeg.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            lowerLeftLeg.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(),
            leftFoot.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()
        };
    }

    public Vector3 CalculateCenterOfMass()
    {
        var mass = Vector3.zero;
        float division = 0;

        foreach (var t in _rigidbodies)
        {
            var objMass = t.mass;
            mass += objMass * t.transform.position;
            division += objMass;
        }

        return mass / division;
    }
}

``
```

Again, huge thank you to MetalCore999 (Youtube) for publishing his original script.